# Zend Framework - All pages keep redirecting to HTTP

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a website that is hosted on 2 different server with similar specification.

Hosted on staging server, just implemented a .htaccess to force user to go through https://www.domain.com

However, I realize on the production server, the application keeps redirecting to http:// instead. I cannot figure out where is wrong in the code!? The codes are exactly the same.

Comment: There is not enough information to help you. Plus you already asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757740/https-not-working-keeps-redirecting-to-http I suggest look at your logs, enable mod_rewrite logging and stop trying to diagnose in the dark. :)

Comment: Did you configure your routing configuration to have a scheme-route as base for all subroutes? Without that ZF will only match your http:// routes

Comment: Pardon my silly question, I don't think there is any such routing configuration. How can I achieve that and where?

Comment: In my mind if you imagine this as a two-element system (application + server) and one of the elements is constant, but the outcome is different then it's a problem with the other element (server) and not the application. Anyway schemat routes are described --> http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-scheme

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. The system administrator is able to prove that https is working, outside this application. I read about your tutorial. May I know where should I include the Route::Scheme?